# Гутен морген. Joomla модули, проблема

Tags: шаблоны, joomla

Итак, это опять я. На виртуалке стоит денвер, установила все что нужно, скачала шаблон классный под joomla 1.5, установилось все прекрасно, но потом я начала естественно включать модули, половина из них мне показывает ошибки, вообще не отображает сам модуль, к примеру: Warning: DB reports: DB function failed with error number 1146
Table 'joom.jos_sobi2_config' doesn't exist SQL=SELECT `configValue`, `configKey` FROM `jos_sobi2_config` in L:homelocalhostwwwsuncomponentscom_sobi2config.class.php on line 1079
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in L:homelocalhostwwwsuncomponents

Что в БД не так или шаблон кривой- не понимаю, мозг уже не варит, буду рада за ответ.
Пы.Сы : если есть у кого сайт нормальный с нормальными работающими шаблонами- не в службу а в дружбу подскажите. =)

Comment: Welcome to opensource =)
Ошибки разные или выглядят примерно одинаково?

Comment: Из той ошибки что привели понятно что у вас в бд нету таблицы jos_sobi2_config, где же она ? :D

Comment: oo таблицу нужно наверное вручную добавить ...попробую все сделать, просто в ошибках не очень понимаю.

Comment: Я с таким никогда не сталкивался, хотя несколько сайтов на джумле сделал. Вы включаете модули, которые вместе с ней шли?

Comment: Да, но даже когда отдельно их скачала все та же проблемма была до тех пор пока сама вручную не создала таблицы)

Comment: Welcome to opensource это к чему? Linux тоже opensource кагбы